# What is this phenomenon called, and what is a word for/simpler variation for this related phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever I get into a disagreement with an individual I notice that this phenomenon always occurs. (I either notice it during the argument or afterward.) Allow me to provide you with an instance to help describe exactly what I am talking about:

I am having a disagreement with an individual regarding bottled water VS tap water. I am supporting the consumption of tap water and simultaneously attacking bottled water. At one point, it seems like I have won the argument as my points outweigh his. However, he then starts bringing up additional points and he now feels that he has won that argument. I tell him, "Any argument could be supported with the English language, due to its vast vocabulary, but my points are logical and outweigh yours".

Therefore, here is a summary of what I am asking for help with:

1. What is this phenomenon called when someone uses the vast vocabulary of the English language and all associated knowledge to formulate points to support their argument?
2. What is a good word for this phrase/How could this phrase be reworded to a simpler form without out sounding cruel? - "any argument could be supported with the English language, due to its vast vocabulary, but that my points are logical and outweigh yours"

Comment: I'm a bit lost. The number of words in the English language has little to do with how logical an argument is. I don't think **any** argument can be supported with the English language, though any argument can be *argued* in any language.

Comment: Do you mean that your interlocutor keeps adding on so many arguments that you can't possibly refute all of them? Or that they use fancy rhetoric to hide bad arguments?

Comment: Answer to Alphabet: Yes, the fancy rhetoric to hide a bad argument is definitely something. Is there a single word that describes that?

Comment: Answer to Alphabet: The addition of many arguments is also something I am interested in. For instance, the interlocutor does not give up (They have an ego and believe they cannot loose an argument) and provide shitty arguments that they believe completely shift the winning, when in reality they are shitty arguments. These arguments might be "packaged" in fancy rhetoric as you said in the second part of your answer. What would this phenomenon be called?

Comment: Question is very unclear. There are terms like [Gish gallop](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop) but this works in any language. There might be a specific name for when you use lots of different words to refer to the same thing to confuse people?

Comment: Perhaps the other person is using one of [these types of fallacy](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Logical_fallacy). But without their actual words in context, we cannot tell.

Comment: They are (if convincing) using specious arguments, exploiting in this case polysemy and other sources of ambiguity.

Comment: Does this boil down to when, how or why he starts bringing up additional points, which involves describes very different things.

One brings up extra, supporting points.

The other brings up different points, little to do with the real argument.

Could you rephrase at least the title?

The pitch is queered by ‘Whenever… always…’ which combination suggests you’re not sure what you’re saying…
‘I either notice it during the argument or afterward’ will be broadly understood, but should be ‘I notice it either during the argument or afterward’  Do you really think they’re the same?

Answer (score 0):

> "Any argument could be supported with the English language, due to its vast vocabulary, but that my points are logical and outweigh his."

I suggest that at least one of your opponent's strategies is

**Semantics** (n.)

> *Chiefly depreciative*. The use of words with particular meanings, esp. for euphemistic or tendentious purposes. Also: (the act of
> making) pedantic distinctions regarding the precise or technical meaning of words; **verbal quibbling.**
>
> **1978**   K. Hudson *Jargon of Professions* 16   Whenever a newsman raises his hand to ask for clarification of some mealy-mouthed
> statement: ‘I am not going to debate **semantics** with you,’ the
> spokesman replies.
>
> **2008**   J. Picoult *Change of Heart* 26   The doctors say I won't die
> from AIDS—I'll die from pneumonia or TB..; but if you ask me, **that's
> just semantics**. Dead is dead. [OED]

> Loosely, **deliberate distortion or twisting of meaning**, as in some
> types of advertising, propaganda, etc. [*Webster's New World
> Dictionary*, Third College Ed.]

---

> **Semantics** is the study of meaning in a language. ... It is now the most widely used label for such a science, despite the popular
> **pejorative sense** which has developed in everyday speech (as in **"That's
> just semantics," *i.e.* quibbling unnecessarily over word
> meanings, or deliberately using language to mislead or confuse.**)
> [David Crystal; *Clinical Linguistics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clinical_Linguistics/AYC4BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22semantics%22%20quibbling&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> When we say something is '**a question of semantics**', we are
> referring to the hazardous nature of actually pinning down, with any
> exactitude, the meaning of what a person has communicated. [James
> Watson, Anne Hill; *Dictionary of Media and Communication*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Media_and_Communication_St/XKP-63dSKNsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20question%20of%20semantics%22%20means&pg=PA171&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think you've made plausible points but the other person is hellbent on proving themselves right, you could say that they are **beating about the bush**. In other words, because they lack content or can't substantiate their argument they pad it out with bilge.

Here's *The Farlex Dictionary* defining the idiom:

> discuss a matter without coming to the point; be ineffectual and waste time. *This phrase is a metaphor which originated in the shooting or netting of birds.*

*I don't want to beat about the bush. Mr Adams is threatening to leave us.* (*1992*) *Barry Unsworth Sacred Hunger*

[beat about the bush](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+about+the+bush)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting OP's comments, which are clearer than the question:

"shitty arguments ... 'packaged' in fancy rhetoric... Is there a single word [for that]?"

There is an English phrase, "empty rhetoric", which fits the bill if you will allow a phrase.

But it's misguided to think that this is particular to English.

Answer (score 0):

> In modern usage, sophism, sophist, and sophistry are used
> disparagingly.
>
> A sophism, or sophistry, is a fallacious argument, especially one used
> deliberately to deceive.
>
> A sophist is a person who reasons with *clever* but *fallacious* and
> *deceptive* arguments.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophist#:%7E:text=In%20modern%20usage%2C%20sophism%2C%20sophist,but%20fallacious%20and%20deceptive%20arguments.)]; emphasis mine

> **sophistry** [uncountable noun]
>
> [formal] Sophistry is the practice of using clever arguments that
> sound convincing but are in fact false.
>
> - *Political selection is more dependent on sophistry and less on economic literacy.*   Synonyms: fallacy, quibble, casuistry, sophism

[[Collins COBUILD Advanced Learner’s Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sophistry)] ['in British English']

> 1a. a method of argument that is seemingly plausible
> though actually invalid and                         misleading
>
> b. the art of using such arguments
>
> 2. subtle but unsound or fallacious reasoning
> 3. an instance of this; a sophism

[[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sophistry)]